# Getting unique key error even I put the key all components

Tags: reactjs

I put the key prop to parent component but it gives unique key error. Even I put the key props to every element still getting this error. How can I fix this problem?

```
{orders &&
            orders.slice(0).reverse().map((order) =>

              order.order_type === 'PickupOrders' && 
                <Row key={uuidv4()} align="middle" style={{ height: '6vh', borderBottom: '1px solid #e6ebe7' }} justify="center" >
                  
                  <Col span={9} key={uuidv4()} >
                    <p key={uuidv4()} style={{ marginBottom: 'auto', marginTop: 'auto' , textAlign:'center'}}>{order.customer_fullname}</p>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={9} key={uuidv4()}>
                    <p key={uuidv4()} style={{ marginBottom: 'auto', marginTop: 'auto' , textAlign:'center'}} >{order.order_status}</p>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={6}  key={uuidv4()}>
                    <p key={uuidv4()} style={{ marginBottom: 'auto', marginTop: 'auto' , textAlign:'center'}} >{order.total_price}</p>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              
            )}


{counter > 0 &&
            _.times( counter , (i) => (
              <div style={{ height: '6vh', borderBottom: '1px solid #e6ebe7' }} >
                <Dropdown
                  key={uuidv4()}
                  overlay={menu( PickUpOrder(orders, counter - i), openModalFunc)}
                  placement='bottomCenter'
                  trigger={['click']}
                >
                  <IconButton
                    color='primary'
                    aria-label='add an alarm'
                  >
                    <MoreVertIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Dropdown>
              </div>
            ))
          }
```

Comment: can you show me your uuidv4() function ?

Comment: its a unique key producer that called uuid , you can find on net

Comment: .map((order, index) => try to use index as key of <Row /> and remove all other key from <Col />.

Comment: No need to have `keys` defined for your `Col` and `p` . Keys should be at the top level . Just have your key defined in the `Row`

Comment: `key` have to be the same at each render, otherwise react assumes it's a new Component (so unmount the preivous one, and mounts a new one). `uuidv4` generates a new key at each render

Comment: What is "this error"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part looks fine. When you **map** or **_.times** in order to iterate arrays or array of objects, key attribute should be in top tag. In your case;

```
 _.times( counter , (i) => (
              <div style={{ height: '6vh', borderBottom: '1px solid #e6ebe7' }} key={uuidv4()}> {/* <---- */}
                <Dropdown
                  overlay={menu( PickUpOrder(orders, counter - i), openModalFunc)}
                  placement='bottomCenter'
                  trigger={['click']}
                > ...
```

I hope it works fine.